# Why is my string only accepting three characters?

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to check if all the vowels are present in a given string or not. If they are present in the string, then the output should be "YES", otherwise it should be "NO". I have also printed the values of `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, and `u` (counter variables), but the problem is that this string accepts only the first 3 letters, and not more than that.

Here if I enter the string as "aeiouqw", the output is:

> a:1
>   e:1
>   i:1
>   o:0
>   u:0
>   NO

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int j=0;
    int a,e,i,o,u;
    a=e=i=o=u=0;
    string s;
    cout<<"Enter the string:";
    do
    {
        cin>>s[j++];
    }while(s[j]!='\0');

    int k=0;

    while(s[k]!='\0')
    {
        switch(s[k++])
        {
        case 'a':a++;
            break;
        case 'e':e++;
             break;
        case 'i':i++;
             break;
        case 'o':o++;
             break;
        case 'u':u++;
             break;
        default:break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"a: "<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"e: "<<e<<endl;
    cout<<"i: "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"o: "<<o<<endl;
    cout<<"u: "<<u<<endl;

    if((a>0)&&(e>0)&&(i>0)&&(o>0)&&(u>0))
    {cout<<"YES";}
    else
    {cout<<"NO";}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do? What makes you think you can access elements of a `std::string` before you put anything in there?

Comment: You should try using Arrays and better variable names, because the current code you have is very hard to understand.

Comment: `do
    {
        cin>>s[j++];
    }while(s[j]!='\0');` --> `cin>>s;`

Comment: @closevoters Just choosing _unclear what you're asking_ is a bit of too ignorant and not the correct close reason. Though questions about undefined behavior are a bit hard to answer actually, and rarely give a good source for future research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your question title:

> **Why is my string only accepting three characters?**

That's because you are calling [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) using the statements

```
do
{
    cin>>s[j++]; // <<<< UB here ...
} while(s[j]!='\0');  // <<< ... and here
```

The `string s;` variable isn't initialized (`size` is still `0` at this point), and dereferencing an arbitrary position like `s[j++]` isn't defined. Anything can happen, including the behavior you experience, or your hard disk gets formatted, or nasal demons flying out from your nostrils.

---

The simplest way to fix that is just replace your whole loop with

```
cin>>s;
```

or

```
getline(cin, s);
```

if you want to accept input containing any whitespace characters.

Both statements mentioned above will resize your `string s;` variable properly.

Comment: _your hard disk gets formatted, or nasal demons flying out from your nostrils_ seems a bit on the over the top side and is overblowing undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PeterSW: You'll never know. Just think about someone's car keys ;)

Comment: @PeterSW It's just some [common jargon](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), at least for old farts like me ;-) ...

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the input the wrong way. You should use the [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function instead of your `do/while` loop (see article: [Using cin to get user input](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/)):

```
cout<<"Enter the string:";    
getline(cin, s);
```

This solves the problem with your uninitialized string `s` that you are accessing in your `do/while` loop, because `getline()` replaces any content in `s` by the newly extracted sequence from `cin`. For the `getline()` function you have to add the following include:

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

Then you will get the following output for your test string:

> Enter the string:aeiouqw
>   a: 1
>   e: 1
>   i: 1
>   o: 1
>   u: 1
>   YES

Answer (score 1):

your code is rather confusing. simplify it by first using better variable names and more whitespace to separate different sections. it all helps for readability.

also it would be easier to just iterate through each char in the string, and test if it is a vowel, if so accumulate the counter.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, e, i, o, u;
    a = e = i = o = u = 0;

    string str;
    cout << "Enter the string: ";

    cin >> str;

    for (int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++) {
        if (str[index] == 'a') {
            a++;
        }
        else if (str[index] == 'e') {
            e++;
        }
        else if (str[index] == 'i') {
            i++;
        }
        else if (str[index] == 'o') {
            o++;
        }
        else if (str[index] == 'u') {
            u++;
        }
    }


    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "e: " << e << endl;
    cout << "i: " << i << endl;
    cout << "o: " << o << endl;
    cout << "u: " << u << endl;

    if ((a>0) && (e>0) && (i>0) && (o>0) && (u>0))
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Daniel I suppose I should've been more clear. You are very right, a switch statement would easily work as well ( and in longer lists are much faster to use even). I was referring more to of using the 'for' loop instead of the 'do while' loop to iterate through the string because his use of it was confusing.

Comment: @amallard Completely agree the `for` is neater (if this was tagged c++11 then range-`for` would be even better!).